# How to test helper with params

Tags: ruby, minitest

I tried to test a method in helper with params[:a]. I'm not using Rspec so don't know how to solve it.

In helper file:

```py
def get_commands(filter)
  order_by = params[:order_by]
  something else(filter)
end
```

and the test file:

```py
test 'get_commands works' do
  filter = something
  res = get_commands(filter)
end
```

It shows: `` NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' ``
and it also doesn't work if I just add 
`params[:order_by]='desc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty generic approach is to use dependency injection.

First, change the method to accept params as an argument:

```
def get_commands(filter, params)
  order_by = params[:order_by]
  something else(filter)
end
```

Make sure to include this new argument in the controller when you call the method.

Then you can pass a mock parameter set in your test:

```
test 'get_commands works' do
  filter = something
  mock_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(order_by: :id)
  res = get_commands(filter, mock_params)
  # ... make your expectation about the result. 
end
```

As a caveat, dependency injection is sometimes treated like an antipattern. Rails does have some built in helpers for testing controllers, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers. But using dependency injection like this would definitely work, and is a bit simpler.